# ImportError: No module named langchain.llms

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I used the following import statetement:

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
```

And I am getting the following error:

> pycode python main.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "main.py", line 1, in 
> from langchain.llms import openai ImportError: No module named langchain.llms

I am using Python 3.11.6 and I installed the packages using

```
pip3 install openai langchain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

it works with

```
Version: 0.0.274
```

the latest `langchain` version is 0.0.320 and try to import like this:

```
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI
```

Maybe your python version installed an early verison of langchain due to dependency requirements

Comment: and how do I check the `langchain` version?

Comment: `pip show langchain`

Comment: yep, I tried that only to see that I do not have Python or pip installed. Makes no sense I have run `brew install python` a couple of times already, I even tried with `pyenv`. I mean my machine does not even give me Python 2.7 anymore and I definitely did not uninstall it.